# How to get the called address with WCF from inside the service method implementation?

Tags: wcf, ip-address

Inside the WCF service implementation I need to get the service address. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe `OperationContext.Current.EndpointDispatcher.EndpointAddress` might have the info you're looking for.